# Items disappear while changing worlds

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am playing on a server that runs **3 worlds**: Main / Survival /Village.

I played on this server 1 week using my old pc on **version 1.8.8.**
I had same items in my inventory no matter which world I joined.

Then I switched to my new pc, but ran the server with **version 1.8.0.**
Now I have same items while swapping between Main and Survival, but Village world has different items, therefore what I collect on survival world, cannot be transferred to village or main.

Is there any way I could fix it? I reinstalled my minecraft game, although I did not contact server support thinking the fault is on my client's side.

Comment: Looks to me like a server side issue.

Comment: Why did you start playing with an **older** version on the new PC?

Comment: which plugin do you use for world switching, you most likely just have to change the config

Answer (score -1):

When changing worlds the items you hold in your inventory and in your hotbar are stored in the world folder, not the server. If you want these items, open the folder with the world you had your inventory in and find the stats folder. In there, open the folder `playerdata` and find the file with your UUID, which you can find on websites like NameMC. When you find it, it will be a `.dat` file. That file has all your player's data for that world. You can copy this file over to your other world's `playerdata` folder and changes will take effect when you restart your server. If you do this while the server is open it  will null anything you just did so you'll have to start over. If you also want achievements and stats you can find the `stats` folder and find your UUID and copy and paste the file into your other world's `stats` folder. Note that both of these methods will override any stats / inventory in your new world.

Comment: They are not the server operator. They have no access to the server's files.

Comment: This is a server side issue and can only be fixed by the OP. You shouldn't down vote answers because they didn't fix your issue. It's not possible to fix this issue if you are not the server operator. – LionWaffles just now   edit   delete

Answer (score -2):

For most plugins that involve world switching or multiple worlds, there is a corresponding plugin or an entry in the config file to enable inventory backups / transferring. I would also recommend checking the plugin page for updates, or contacting the developer about the issue if you cannot find a config entry or a plugin. When I had a server, I used a plugin called [Multiverse](https://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/multiverse-core/). It had a corresponding Inventories plugin **and** a very comprehensive config and documentation.

If there is a way to import your worlds into Multiverse, I would strongly advise doing that as a last resort. The command is `/mv import <directory name>` If you need any more help, I would be happy to assist.

Comment: They are not the server operator.

Comment: This is a server side issue and can only be fixed by the OP. You shouldn't down vote answers because they didn't fix your issue. It's not possible to fix this issue if you are not the server operator. – LionWaffles just now   edit   delete